# IsFlush boolean

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

I have this method `IsFlush`, that checks if a hand of cards is flush. I also have another method `SuitHist`, that creates a histogram of how many Suits are in a hand. The purpose of `IsFlush` is to count the Suits in the array, and if 5 or more Suits are the same, to return true. However, when I try to initialise `SuitHist` into an Integer array `flush`, the parameter of SuitHist give an error, any help I can get with this?

```
    public static int[] SuitHist(Card[] hand) {
        int[] histSuit = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
            histSuit[hand[i].suit]++;
        }
        return histSuit;
    }

    public static boolean IsFlush(Cards[] deck) {
        int[] flush = SuitHist(deck);
        for (int i = 0; i < flush.length; i++) {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (flush[i] >= 5)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `Cards[]` ? Do you have such type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo. `SuitHist` is expecting an array of type `Card[]` but in `IsFlush` you have deck as type `Cards[]`. Try changing the function like so:

```
public static boolean IsFlush(Card[] deck){
....
}
```